# How do I run a bat file in the background from another bat file?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, cmd

I have a "setup" script which I run in the morning which starts all the programs that I need. Now some of those need additional setup of the environment, so I need to wrap them in small BAT scripts.

How do I run such a script on Windows XP in the background?

`CALL env-script.bat` runs it synchronously, i.e. the setup script can continue only after the command in the env-script has terminated.

`START/B env-script.bat` runs another instance of CMD.exe in the same command prompt, leaving it in a really messy state (I see the output of the nested CMD.exe, keyboard is dead for a while, script is not executed).

`START/B CMD env-script.bat` yields the same result. None of the flags in CMD seem to match my bill.

Comment: `which I run in the morning which starts all the programs that I need` we are the same! haha ~ everytime I start the PC, I need to run many programs before working.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Actually, the following works fine for me and creates new windows:

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
start test2.cmd
start test3.cmd
echo Foo
pause
```

test2.cmd

```
@echo off
echo Test 2
pause
exit
```

test3.cmd

```
@echo off
echo Test 3
pause
exit
```

Combine that with parameters to `start`, such as `/min`, as Moshe pointed out if you don't want the new windows to spawn in front of you.

Comment: Okay, this works but isn't 100% perfect: After I press "RETURN" in "Test 2", that window doesn't close. Any ideas?

Comment: You can add "exit" to the spawned batches to close them afterwards again. Sorry, didn't test that far :)

Comment: in fact the start script1.bat \n start script2.bat \n start scriptN.bat was sufficient for me

Answer (score 160):

Two years old, but for completeness...

**Standard, inline approach:** (i.e. behaviour you'd get when using `&` in Linux)

```
START /B CMD /C CALL "foo.bat" [args [...]]
```

Notes: 1. `CALL` is paired with the .bat file because that where it usually goes..  (i.e. This is just an extension to the `CMD /C CALL "foo.bat"` form to make it asynchronous.  Usually, it's required to correctly get exit codes, but that's a non-issue here.); 2. Double quotes around the .bat file is only needed if the name contains spaces.  (The name could be a path in which case there's more likelihood of that.).

**If you don't want the output:**

```
START /B CMD /C CALL "foo.bat" [args [...]] >NUL 2>&1
```

**If you want the bat to be run on an independent console:** (i.e. another window)

```
START CMD /C CALL "foo.bat" [args [...]]
```

**If you want the other window to hang around afterwards:**

```
START CMD /K CALL "foo.bat" [args [...]]
```

Note: This is actually poor form unless you have users that specifically want to use the opened window as a normal console.  If you just want the window to stick around in order to see the output, it's better off putting a `PAUSE` at the end of the bat file. Or even yet, add `^& PAUSE` after the command line:

```
START CMD /C CALL "foo.bat" [args [...]] ^& PAUSE
```

Comment: `&` is an "and then" (terminology?) operator.  (e.g. `cmd1 & cmd2` means do "cmd1" and then "cmd2".  Unlike the `&&` operator, execution of "cmd2" doesn't depend on the successful exit of "cmd1".)  The `^` escapes the `&` so that it goes into CMD's arguments instead of being consumed and run by the same console that ran START.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks.  I was just about to port some scripts to Linux, because other guides to `start` and `cmd` didn't give the full functionality I sought.  Your answer nails it.

Comment: If you don't want the output then the redirection must be escaped so that it gets passed to CMD. Also CALL is not needed: `START /B "" CMD /C "foo.bat" [args [...]] ^>nul 2^>^&1`

Comment: @dbenham: Although what you're saying makes sense, `START /B "" CMD /C PING 127.0.0.1 >NUL` seems to work regardless and nothing is output.  (Probably because `CMD` inherits `START`'s I/O handles.)  I guess the difference is if you want to keep `START`'s (error) output intact, which is probably a good idea.  `CALL` is just there because I felt it's a good practice to keep.  (i.e. Not using `CALL` for *synchronous* bat calls will result in unpredictable exit codes, so I consistently pair bat calls with `CALL` even when it doesn't strictly apply, such as in this case.)

Comment: Worked with me like a charm.
FOR %%y IN (* --dev-- *) DO START /B CMD /C CALL "%%y"

Answer (score 9):

Since START is the only way to execute something in the background from a CMD script, I would recommend you keep using it. Instead of the /B modifier, try /MIN so the newly created window won't bother you. Also, you can set the priority to something lower with /LOW or /BELOWNORMAL, which should improve your system responsiveness.

Comment: -1 The problem is that START doesn't create a new window when you start a BAT file; instead it reuses the current window and mixes the I/O two CMD processes.

Comment: It is not creating a new window because you're using the /B flag. Remove it.

Answer (score 6):

Other than foreground/background term.
Another way to hide running window is via vbscript, if is is still available in your system.

```
DIM objShell
set objShell=wscript.createObject("wscript.shell")
iReturn=objShell.Run("yourcommand.exe", 0, TRUE)
```

name it as sth.vbs and call it from bat, put in sheduled task, etc.
PersonallyI'll disable vbs with no haste at any Windows system I manage :)

Comment: For my particular use case, this was actually the only solution I could get to work...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new C# Windows application and call this method from main:

```
public static void RunBatchFile(string filename)
{
    Process process = new Process();

    process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;

    // suppress output (command window still gets created)
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "> NULL";

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Uhm ... I was hoping that something as simple as that wouldn't need installing Visual Studio ...

Comment: Until PowerShell is available 100% - C# is really overkill.

Comment: Aaron: The C# compiler is included in the .NET Framework 2, so you can just edit some code in a text editor and compile it. Still, since this is perfectly possible in a batch file I'd also say C# is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my Windows XP Home installation, the Unix way:

```
call notepad.exe &
```

Comment: I think this only works by coincidence, and the & isn't necessary.

Comment: Yeah, notepad.exe is asynchronous to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Actually is quite easy with this option at the end:

> c:\start BATCH.bat -WindowStyle Hidden

Comment: the Windows command `start` does not have a `-WindowStyle` option.

Comment: @Stephan Arreed. The odd path (`C:\` instead of `C:\Windows\`) suggests that he found a tool somewhere on the internet and copied on his hard drive.