# Running Windows batch file commands asynchronously

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Say, if I have

- foo.exe
- bar.exe
- baz.exe

How do I run all of them from a batch file asynchronously, i.e. without waiting for the previous program to stop?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Using the [`START`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command to run each program should get you what you need:

```
START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

Every `START` invocation runs the command given in its parameter and returns immediately, unless executed with a `/WAIT` switch.

That applies to command-line apps. Apps without command line return immediately anyway, so to be sure, if you want to run all asynchronously, use `START`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I should have read each entry of `help` carefully. :)

Comment: Shameless self-advertising: I once created a batch which is able to function as some kind of thread pool, just for processes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes/676667#676667

Comment: If you need to provide arguments or if the path to the commands contains spaces remember to add quotes. In this case you also need to provide a title for the opening console window: start "" "[path to command]" [command args]

Comment: *"Apps without command line return immediately anyway"* – Are you sure? [Why GUI application blocks a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19381082/850848)

Answer (score 76):

Combining a couple of the previous answers, you could try `start /b cmd /c foo.exe`.

For a trivial example, if you wanted to print out the versions of java/groovy/grails/gradle, you could do this in a batch file:

```
@start /b cmd /c java -version
@start /b cmd /c gradle -version
@start /b cmd /c groovy -version
@start /b cmd /c grails -version
```

If you have something like Process Explorer (Sysinternals), you will see a few child cmd.exe processes each with a java process (as per the above commands). The output will print to the screen in whatever order they finish.

```
start /b :  Start application without creating a new window. The
             application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
             enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
             the application

cmd /c : Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```

Comment: it prevents the command from being echoed to the console. In batch scripts, sometimes you'll see `echo off` at the beginning which, when you execute the script, will prevent all the commands from being echoed to the console. The `@` is similar but just for that single command. So, sometimes you'll see `@echo off`.

Comment: Did not work for me.  Still stopped waiting for the application to close before it moved on.

Answer (score 41):

You can use the start command to spawn background processes without launching new windows:

`start /b foo.exe`

The new process will not be interruptable with CTRL-C; you can kill it only with CTRL-BREAK (or by closing the window, or via Task Manager.)

Comment: Where is `BREAK` on keyboards these days?

Comment: @user2023370 Still on the [Pause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ANSI_Keyboard_Layout_Diagram_with_Form_Factor.svg) key. Most laptops that lack certain keys support [hidden key combinations](https://support.lenovo.com/at/en/documents/ht074004).

Comment: @user2023370 [Pause/Break key on modern keyboards](http://superuser.com/q/12525/241386) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key#Modern_keyboards

Comment: Did not work for me.  Still stopped waiting for the application to close before it moved on.

Answer (score 26):

Create a batch file with the following lines:

```
start foo.exe
start bar.exe
start baz.exe
```

The [start command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) runs your command in a new window, so all 3 commands would run asynchronously.

Comment: works as long as you don't have a path with spaces..  Then when you put double quotes around it, it thinks in a title, not an application.   This works.  START "VMPlayer" /D "C:\Users\gavin\Virtual Machines\CentOS 8 64-bit" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\vmplayer.exe"

Answer (score 19):

Use the [START command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

```
start [programPath]
```

If the path to the program contains spaces remember to add quotes. In this case you also need to provide a title for the opening console window

```
start "[title]" "[program path]"
```

If you need to provide arguments append them at the end (outside the command quotes)

```
start "[title]" "[program path]" [list of command args]
```

Use the /b option to avoid opening a new console window (but in that case you cannot interrupt the application using CTRL-C

Answer (score 11):

There's a third (and potentially much easier) option.  If you want to spin up multiple instances of a single program, using a Unix-style command processor like Xargs or GNU Parallel can make that a fairly straightforward process.

There's a win32 Xargs clone called [PPX2](http://www.pirosa.co.uk/demo/wxargs/wxargs.html) that makes this fairly straightforward.

For instance, if you wanted to transcode a directory of video files, you could run the command:

```
dir /b *.mpg |ppx2 -P 4 -I {} -L 1 ffmpeg.exe -i "{}" -quality:v 1 "{}.mp4"
```

Picking this apart, `dir /b *.mpg` grabs a list of .mpg files in my current directory, the `|` operator pipes this list into ppx2, which then builds a series of commands to be executed in parallel; 4 at a time, as specified here by the `-P 4` operator.  The `-L 1` operator tells ppx2 to only send one line of our directory listing to ffmpeg at a time.

After that, you just write your command line (`ffmpeg.exe -i "{}" -quality:v 1 "{}.mp4"`), and `{}` gets automatically substituted for each line of your directory listing.

It's not universally applicable to every case, but is a whole lot easier than using the batch file workarounds detailed above.  Of course, if you're not dealing with a list of files, you could also pipe the contents of a textfile or any other program into the input of pxx2.

Comment: The latest xargs win32 port works well nowadays (the one included with git for windows anyway).

Comment: This is great except it fails dealing with files containing unicode characters. Any plans to support unicode files? Thanks.

Comment: @GökhanSever In the past I've worked around this issue by using the "short name" form of the path, that looks like  C:\PROGRA~1\WINDOW~3\MYPROG~1.EXE. Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get anything to work I ended up just using powershell to start bat scripts .. sometimes even start cmd /c does not work not sure why .. I even tried stuff like start cmd /c notepad & exit

```
start-Process "c:\BACKUP\PRIVATE\MobaXterm_Portable\MobaXterm_Portable.bat" -WindowStyle Hidden
```