# Possible to launch multiple threads of commands in cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, multiprocessing

I have about 290 files that I need to optimize in a short period of time.

When I do `optipng *.png` it takes about 10 minutes to complete the transaction.

However when I do `optipng a*.png` and `optipng m*.png` in two separate command line it gets the work done in 5 minutes.

Now is there a way I can launch about 20 processes at the same time which will get the work done faster and not take up all of the space on my Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

I have written a batch file that executes only a maximum number of commands a while ago: [Parallel execution of shell processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes/676667#676667):

> ```
> @echo off
> for /l %%i in (1,1,20) do call :loop %%i
> goto :eof
>
> :loop
> call :checkinstances
> if %INSTANCES% LSS 5 (
>     rem just a dummy program that waits instead of doing useful stuff
>     rem but suffices for now
>     echo Starting processing instance for %1
>     start /min wait.exe 5 sec
>     goto :eof
> )
> rem wait a second, can be adjusted with -w (-n 2 because the first ping returns immediately;
> rem otherwise just use an address that's unused and -n 1)
> echo Waiting for instances to close ...
> ping -n 2 ::1 >nul 2>&1
> rem jump back to see whether we can spawn a new process now
> goto loop
> goto :eof
>
> :checkinstances
> rem this could probably be done better. But INSTANCES should contain the number of running instances afterwards.
> for /f "usebackq" %%t in (`tasklist /fo csv /fi "imagename eq wait.exe"^|wc -l`) do set INSTANCES=%%t
> goto :eof
> ```
>
> It spawns a maximum of four new processes that execute in parallel and minimized. Wait time needs to be adjusted probably, depending on how much each process does and how long it is running. You probably also need to adjust the process name for which tasklist is looking if you're doing something else.
>
> There is no way to properly count the processes that are spawned by this batch, though. One way would be to create a random number at the start of the batch (`%RANDOM%`) and create a helper batch that does the processing (or spawns the processing program) but which can set its window title to a parameter:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> title %1
> "%2" "%3"
> ```
>
> This would be a simple batch that sets its title to the first parameter and then runs the second parameter with the third as argument. You can then filter in tasklist by selecting only processes with the specified window title (`tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq ..."`). This should work fairly reliable and prevents too many false positives. Searching for `cmd.exe` would be a bad idea if you still have some instances running, as that limits your pool of worker processes.
>
> You can use `%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` to create a sensible default of how many instances to spawn.
>
> You can also easily adapt this to use `psexec` to spawn the processes remotely (but wouldn't be very viable as you have to have admin privileges on the other machine as well as provide the password in the batch). You would have to use process names for filtering then, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can write a batch file and run your commands asynchronously from that file.

[Running Windows batch file commands asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449188/running-windows-batch-file-commands-asynchronously)