# batch file to launch an executable file which requires input

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have an executable file that requires a user to input a file name to run.  The exe file will then output a file when it finishes.  (For example, when I run the exe file, it opens in command prompt and has the user input a file name, which will always be a .xlsx file.  When it finishes running, it outputs a .xls file)

I can run 30 instances of the executable simultaneously, for 30 different files.  I want a script that will launch the exe file for the first 30 .xlsx files in the folder, and then every time I get an output file, it will start up another instance of the exe file for the next file in the folder.

I have no idea where to start, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit your post and add what did you tried as code so far ?

Comment: Have you searched?  Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837369/possible-to-launch-multiple-threads-of-commands-in-cmd) as this is something that has come up before.

Answer (score 0):

Change your user input method .

```
user input promt to command line input.
```

pass your input as command line argument.