# Batch Script Run Multiple Jar Files At once

Tags: java, batch-file

I have two batch files which I would like to run at once. So I wrote this:

```
@echo off
java -jar happyjar.jar
java -jar sadjar.jar
pause
```

When I run the script, it first runs happyjar, then runs sadjar. Is it possible to run both jars at once without running multiple batch files?

Comment: Try using javaw instead, but this won't open a console

Comment: In windows, use the `start` command, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449188/running-windows-batch-file-commands-asynchronously

Answer (score 17):

```
@echo off
start "Title1" java -jar happyjar.jar
start "Title2" java -jar sadjar.jar
pause
```

The [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command runs your command in a new window, so all 3 commands would run asynchronously.

Don't add /wait option, otherwise it will wait for this new window to complete before going to the next command.