# How to run multiple jar files at once using shell script?

Tags: shell, batch-file

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554786/batch-script-run-multiple-jar-files-at-once/14556024#14556024) related to Batch script has an answer. But I need same in shell script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just launch your jar adding a & at the end
Example :

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar myjar1.jar &
java -jar myjar2.jar &
java -jar myjar3.jar &
```

If you want the jar keep running after closing the terminal, use nohup :

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup java -jar myjar1.jar &
nohup java -jar myjar2.jar &
nohup java -jar myjar3.jar &
```

I use it in a project, works like a charm.