# How to run a jar file multiple times? CentOS

Tags: java, bash, centos

I'm hoping someone can tell me how to run a jar file (located on Desktop) multiple times with one command?  Ideally without a new terminal window opening for every instance as well.  A bash script would be sufficient too, whatever is easiest for yourself.

Currently I'm just running java -jar filename.jar for each new instance but it gets repetative when I need to have 50 or so instances open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch Script Run Multiple Jar Files At once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554786/batch-script-run-multiple-jar-files-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in {1..50}
  do
    java -jar filename.jar
  done
```

Comment: Is it safe to run a file multiple times?