# Detach program from SSH connection on a windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, ssh, fabric, detach

I need to log in to a Windows server via SSH through a local Python (2.7) script, start a script on the server and then disconnect the SSH connection, so that the local script can continue to run.

As of now, I am using fabric, and the local script will not continue before the remote script is done and the SSH connection is closed.

I have read on a range of forums, but it seems to my (admittedly inexperienced) eyes that most replys use unix commands. I need to be able to log onto a windows machine however.

What can I do?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? You can write a batch script that'll start in the background:

[Running Windows batch file commands asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449188/running-windows-batch-file-commands-asynchronously)