# Running multipule commands in batch at the same time?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get a batch equivalent of `&` from shell.

```
curl --referer http://fs1d-h.st/cxX -o ~/Library/Application\ Support/download.part1 $url1 &
curl --referer http://fs1d-h.st/1w9 -o ~/Library/Application\ Support/download.part2 $url2
```

The first curl command executes in the background, and then runs the second one immediately after the first is started. The result is two downloads (or other commands) running at the same time.

I've looked around and I can seem to find a way to do this in windows cmd. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449188/running-windows-batch-file-commands-asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

```
start "" "program1" && start "" "program2" [/wait]
```

only use wait if you want to wait for the second one to finish before returning control to the shell or batch file that called it.

Answer (score 0):

@echo off

start file1 "location" | start file2 "location" *most recommended

start file1 "location" && start file2 "location"

Comment: in this answer start explorer is used to start the windows folder environment the path is not intended to locate explorer it is telling explorer what path to open