# Execute php script from php page asynchronously in WINDOWS system

Tags: php, windows, asynchronous

I have been searching through several questions similar to this but i have found no answer suitable for me, especially for Windows system.
I have installed PHP and Apache ona Windows machine. I have an app which calls Page1.php. In Page1 i execute some code and at an specific point I would like to launchanother php script, let`s call it Script.php asynchronously. I don´t need to pass any parameter to this second script -if I could it could be helpful but it´s not mandatory- and I don´t need to wait for the script to finish beacuse i don´t want to retain the communication with the user, since script makes a lot of operations with files and it can last quite a long time.
I have seen and tried answers based on exec, popen, shell, system and so on...but I haven´t found the right one for me, maybe because I´m working on Windows.These have beeen some of the solutions I have tried without anysuccess:

```
exec('php script.php &> /dev/null &');
shell_exec('php script.php &> /dev/null &');
system('php script.php &> /dev/null &');
php script.php &> /dev/null &`
```

The schema could be more or less as follows:

PAGE1.PHP

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
echo "\n";
....
if ($var>$var2) {
    HERE CALL SCRIPT.PHP ASYNC
}
...
?>
```

SCRIPT.php

```
<?php
...
...
?>
```

Comment: Did you try that command at the command line?  It produces a syntax error, because &> doesn't mean anything in Windows.  (Neither does /dev/null.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call "asynchronous" is not actually asynchronous. You make a call for another script to execute in case `$var > $var2` and it's called an `if-statement`.

If your script has to be in another file, you may try using `include`, `include_once` or `require` or `require_once`:

```
if ($var > $var2) {
    include "Script.php";
}
```

The rest depends on Script.php.

Comment: The OP wants to know how to call another script asynchronously.  The fact that he wants this to happen inside an if-statement is just an irrelevant detail.

Comment: Hi Harry, that is the point. The if statement is completely irrelevant. I need to execute script.php without Page1.php being waiting for it to finish to continue its own line of execution.

Answer (score 2):

Copied from php.net's comments on [exec's page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> This will execute $cmd in the background (no cmd window) without PHP
>   waiting for it to finish, on both Windows and Unix.

```
<?php 
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
} 
?>
```

I did not test this myself, but it was a similar direction to what I was thinking of. 
You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449188/running-windows-batch-file-commands-asynchronously) stackoverflow question for more details (might help).

Comment: But in this approach how I execute Script.php. As i can see from your code it only executes command line, is that right?

Comment: @user3188554 The command can be used to start another script. Look at the ["Command Line PHP on Microsoft Windows"](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php) page of php.net to find out how to do it on your machine.

Comment: OK, I almost got it but it is not still working, I guess the problem is the account permissions. Maybe the account needs to have admin privileges, does that make sense?

Comment: @user3188554 it does. You can try running your script using the same command  you use here and see if it works. If it doesn't- try running cmd as administrator and try again- if it works, you should make sure you always execute this as an administrator.
If that is not the issue, you can try using WScript.Shell as written in this [php.net comment](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#43917) (I would update my answer accordingly if it works).