# Terminate process after some time in ADB shell

Tags: android, shell, timeout, adb

I am running an app from ADB shell like this:

```
adb shell am start -n mypackage/.MainActivity
```

I need to terminate the app automatically after 10 seconds and start another application.
I am trying to do something like this:

```
adb shell timeout -t 10 am start -n mypackage/.MainActivity
```

But unfortunately this does not work.

Output:

> /system/bin/sh: timeout not found

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

```
start adb shell am start -n mypackage1/.MainActivity
timout /t 10
kill  mypackage1
start adb shell am start -n mypackage2/.MainActivity
```

[More Info here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#shellcommands)

Comment: i'm running it from windows 10. tried `timeout 10` instead of `sleep 10`. but it still does not work. `timeout 10` does not execute unless the first one completes.

Comment: have you tried the timeout after starting the intent ? i.e the flow should be start the package, pause a certain time, kill the started package, start another package.

Comment: yes i tried your script, just changing the `sleep 10`. The problem is command window waits for the first process to end before executing `timeout 10`. so it waits forever.

Comment: could you give it a try, starting the first application in a separate process which will run asynchronusly ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449188/running-windows-batch-file-commands-asynchronously

Comment: hey, i was exactly looking at this and edited your code. And just now I saw your comment. Thanks, I'm marking this as the correct answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sleep` command running on the device itself:

```
adb shell "am start -W -n mypackage1/.MainActivity; sleep 10; am force-stop mypackage1"
adb shell "am start -W -n mypackage2/.MainActivity"
```

It seems that the app you are trying to start/stop is not designed properly. In this case do:

```
adb shell "(sleep 10; am force-stop mypackage1) & am start -n mypackage1/.MainActivity"
adb shell "am start -n mypackage2/.MainActivity"
```

Comment: can you please tell me what -W is for? the program is waiting indefinitely.  `sleep 10` is never executed.