# how to run a command prompt in background using .bat file(not using .vbs file)

Tags: batch-file

I want to run a .bat file that runs another .bat file in a new cmd, but I want to hide the newly opened cmd or run it in background.
I don't want to use .vbs method. Is there another way possible?

Comment: Please use the search function before posting questions that have more than likely been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449188/running-windows-batch-file-commands-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

There are only really two methods, to sort of simulate it, basically you launch the file without creating a new shell, however, hiding all the commands would make sure it does not show any, also use `cls` as it will ensure that it does not show you what it launches, but it is not fool proof:

**batch1.cmd**

```
start "" /b batch2.cmd
cls
```

**batch2.cmd**

```
@echo off
echo Hello World>nul
ping localhost>nul
(echo hello world>Mytest.txt)>nul
```

The line `(echo hello world>Mytest.txt)>nul` is to simulate how you can pipe infomation to a file, but still pipe the screen output to `nul` so it does not display on screen.

Or you can run the second batch in minimized mode, but that can be maximized or restored by a user:

**batch1.cmd**

```
start "" /min batch2.cmd
```

**batch2.cmd**

```
@echo off
echo Hello World>nul
ping localhost>nul
(echo hello world>Mytest.txt)>nul
```

but, not sure why you do not want to do the `vbs` method as it is surely the best and easiest method.

```
Set MyScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "f:\login.bat", 0, False
```

Comment: if we use vbs method then how to run vbs file. Because on double clicking it opens in notepad

Comment: You can simply associate the file type to open with cscript. Right click any .vbs file, select open with, select always use this program to open the file, select the option to browse file, then browse to `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe` and select open.