# How can i run a .bat file without cmd window popping up?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I have a .bat file that I am trying to run in Jenkins. Jenkins is running as a service so wont recognize the pop ups.
Is there a way I can run this .bat file in silent mode, or not allow the cmd window to pop up?

Comment: A batch file is just a script file which needs a script interpreter. The script interpreter is in this case the *Windows Command Processor* with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` for which is defined by Windows default the environment variable `ComSpec` with that file name as value. `cmd.exe` is a Windows __console__ application. The execution of a batch file from Windows shell (`explorer.exe` running for showing the user a desktop, start menu and taskbar) or a *Windows File Explorer* window (one more instance of `explorer.exe` results always in calling ...

Comment: ... the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with `%ComSpec%` as application to run with the arguments `/c` and the full qualified file name enclosed in `"` as second argument. `explorer.exe` instructs `CreateProcess` to create a console window for the __console__ application `cmd.exe` with using the properties as stored in registry under key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`. That behavior cannot be changed in any way by a user for a single batch file.

Comment: Please show us the lines in the batch file. There is perhaps no batch file needed at all. The general solution for running a console application without a visible console window is using an application which instructs `CreateProcess` with the [process creation flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` set in function parameter `dwCreationFlags`. The Windows __GUI__ version `%SystemRoot%\System32\wscript.exe` of the *Windows Script Host* is such an application.

Comment: A small VBScript file (`.vbs` file) with [.Run](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html) command/function with parameter `intWindowStyle` having value `0` and `bWaitOnReturn` having value `False` is usually used to run a Windows __console__ application completely in background without opening a console window by using a shortcut file (`.lnk` file) with property __Target__ being `%SystemRoot%\System32\wscript.exe "C:\Path\Run Script File.vbs" //B //Nologo`. The usage of `cmd.exe` and a batch file is not needed at all to run a console application with no console window.

Comment: So what would i use here , im a bit confused ?

Comment: there are so many duplicates: [Execute Batch File without Command line visible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23557720/995714), [how not to open a Cmd window when running a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33685398/995714), [how to run a command prompt in background using .bat file(not using .vbs file)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54230872/995714)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute Batch File without Command line visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557720/execute-batch-file-without-command-line-visible)

Comment: What you should do is writing a VBS script file which on interpreting by `%SystemRoot%\System32\wscript.exe` does the same as `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` on interpreting the batch file. There is never the need to use to script interpreters `wscript.exe` and `cmd.exe` for one task. Solutions like how to code a VBS script file interpreted by the *Windows Script Host* just run the *Windows Command Processor*  for interpreting a batch file without getting a console window displayed are stupid solutions in my point of view..

Answer (score 1):

so then you can use the `start` command with `/min` and `/b` switches to run the .bat file in minimized or background mode.

```
start /min /b yourfile.bat
```

Comment: I have tried that , it never seems to end ?

Comment: using this command start /min /b yourfile.bat , it never seems to end ?