# .cmd file on Win10 - How to "multi thread" to have actions fire concurrently?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a .cmd file, used exclusively on Win10, that has a plain jane FOR loop:

```
FOR %%P IN (server1,server3,server4,server5,server6) 
    DO (call _deployment.bat %%P deploy %1 %2)
```

Works great.

I would like to speed up the process, but in a specific way.

1. Start deploy to server1
2. Wait 20 seconds
3. Now start two threads that run concurrently
4. -- one deploys to server 2 and then when 2 is done, deploys 4
5. -- one that deploys to 5 and when 5 is done, deploys 6

I looked into using the START command (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449188/147637) and elsewhere). But that does not seem to be a direct answer (unless I am missing something). For starters, I would need to break one small cmd file into multiple. Simply changing the CALL command to START does not give me the desired behavior.

What is the cmd file path forward?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with cmd batch files? Do you enjoy pain?

Comment: @melpomene They do the job for basic stuff.

Comment: So do other tools, and what you're trying to do now is no longer basic.

Comment: You're doing this to deploy things on multiple servers? Why not use Ansible or Chef?