# How to run one command to multiple servers with Plink in batch

Tags: batch-file, ssh, plink

So far what I have is

```
plink -batch root@1.1.1.1 -pw password COMMAND & plink -batch root@1.1.1.1 -pw password COMMAND
```

the problem is after the first command starts the batch waits for a response from the server to stop the session and go to the next command, I cant seem to find a way to get around this, I'm looking to have it send the command and immediately start the next command on the next server

Answer (score 1):

You can have the server itself execute the command in the background. So you can use the same techniques as with OpenSSH `ssh`, as you will be using server-side functionality, unrelated to the local SSH client you are using:
[Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29142/850848)

So something like this:

```
plink -batch root@1.1.1.1 -pw password "nohup COMMAND > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &"
```

---

Or use local techniques to execute the command asynchronously:
[Running Windows batch file commands asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449188/850848)

So something like this:

```
start "title" /b plink -batch root@1.1.1.1 -pw password COMMAND
```