# list of batch files to execute

Tags: batch-file

I have about 80 batch files. Each one kicks off a copy of data from one machine to another. I would like to maintain 5 simultaneous batch files executing. So I need to start 5 at once and when one finishes it kicks off the next one from a list. The key thing here is "from a list" i.e. I don't want to hard code the sequence as that might result in one of the 5 starters finishing while the others still have work to do. I want the early finisher to pick up the next job from the list.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: @davidjohnobrien You asked 9 questions and accepted only one answer ... are you dissatisfied with the rest?

Comment: This is an old question, but I have a solution for you at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11715437/1012053.

Answer (score 0):

I have once answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes/676667#676667).

Iterating over a sequence should be fairly trivial if you have it either as a list in a single environment variable or a list in multiple environment variables.