# how to run several .cmd files in parallel

Tags: cmd, parallel-processing

I have 4 .cmd files. I want to run then in parallel taking 2 at one time. 
say my files are : 1.cmd, 2.cmd, 3.cmd, 4.cmd

i want to run 1.cmd and 2.cmd in parallel. Now when any of these ends , i want to run 3.cmd and then 4.cmd. In short, at any given time i want 2 of the .cmd files to run.

I am using the Start command for parallel execution. But I am new to scripting and I am getting confused on how to furmulate the above mentioned way of running the cmd files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Debjani

Answer (score 1):

I have given an answer to [“Parallel execution of shell processes”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/672719/73070) once, quoted here:

> Sounds more like you want to use
>   Powershell 2. However, you can spawn
>   new `cmd` windows (or other processes)
>   by using `start`, see also this
>   answer. Although you probably have to
>   use some other tools and a little
>   trickery to create something like a
>   "process pool" (to have only a maximum
>   of *n* instances running at a time).
>   You could achieve the latter by using
>   `tasklist /im` and counting how many
>   are already there (`for` loop or `wc`,
>   if applicable) and simply wait (`ping
>   -n 2 ::1 >nul 2>&1`) and re-check again whether you can spawn a new
>   process.
>
> I have cobbled together a little test
>   batch for this:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> for /l %%i in (1,1,20) do call :loop %%i
> goto :eof
>
> :loop
> call :checkinstances
> if %INSTANCES% LSS 5 (
>     rem just a dummy program that waits instead of doing useful stuff
>     rem but suffices for now
>     echo Starting processing instance for %1
>     start /min wait.exe 5 sec
>     goto :eof
> )
> rem wait a second, can be adjusted with -w (-n 2 because the first ping
> ```
>
> returns immediately;
>       rem otherwise just use an address that's unused and -n 1)
>       echo Waiting for instances to close ...
>       ping -n 2 ::1 >nul 2>&1
>       rem jump back to see whether we can spawn a new process now
>       goto loop
>       goto :eof
>
> ```
> :checkinstances
> rem this could probably be done better. But INSTANCES should contain
> ```
>
> the number of running instances
>   afterwards.
>       for /f "usebackq" %%t in (`tasklist /fo csv /fi "imagename eq
>   wait.exe"^|wc -l`) do set
>   INSTANCES=%%t
>       goto :eof
>
> It spawns a maximum of four new
>   processes that execute in parallel and
>   minimized. Wait time needs to be
>   adjusted probably, depending on how
>   much each process does and how long it
>   is running. You probably also need to
>   adjust the process name for which
>   tasklist is looking if you're doing
>   something else.
>
> There is no way to properly count the
>   processes that are spawned by this
>   batch, though. One way would be to
>   create a random number at the start of
>   the batch (`%RANDOM%`) and create a
>   helper batch that does the processing
>   (or spawns the processing program) but
>   which can set its window title to a
>   parameter:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> title %1
> "%2" "%3"
> ```
>
> This would be a simple batch that sets
>   its title to the first parameter and
>   then runs the second parameter with
>   the third as argument. You can then
>   filter in tasklist by selecting only
>   processes with the specified window
>   title (`tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq
>   ..."`). This should work fairly
>   reliable and prevents too many false
>   positives. Searching for `cmd.exe`
>   would be a bad idea if you still have
>   some instances running, as that limits
>   your pool of worker processes.
>
> You can use `%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%`
>   to create a sensible default of how
>   many instances to spawn.
>
> You can also easily adapt this to use
>   `psexec` to spawn the processes
>   remotely (but wouldn't be very viable
>   as you have to have admin privileges
>   on the other machine as well as
>   provide the password in the batch).
>   You would have to use process names
>   for filtering then, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I assume you can do this with PowerShell.  Use this type of structure:

http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2008/01/30/run-your-powershell-loops-in-parallel/

Within this example you should be able to execute cmd/bat files.

Check out the following thread for some ideas (possible duplicate?)

[Parallel execution of shell processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes)

Comment: Like always i recommend Cygwin for everything.