# Run Java NIO client 25k times using a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, client, nio

I want to run my client program 25,000 times. I need to create a batch file for this purpose. I just want to test my server how many connections it will accept without any delays. I am using `java. nio`. Can anybody help me?

1. I need to know how to create batch file for running a program.
2. How to call Batch file using java program.
3. How to create a batch file which run a java program 25,000 times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @UVM am going to start i need a good example to start. first time am using batch file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run 25k times in sequence:

```
for /l %%x in (1,1,25000) do (java -cp ... MyClass)
```

Run 25000 times in parallel:

```
for /l %%x in (1,1,25000) do (start "" java -cp ... MyClass)
```

If you want to limit the parallelism (which you *should* for such high numbers) then you need a bit more logic. One example is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes/676667#676667).

Comment: can you please explain Run 25k times in sequence / parallel means

Comment: Whether they all run one after another or all at the same time.

Comment: thank youuuuuuu......  if we want to run the prgrm 25k at a time we use parallel rit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put the loop *inside* your client program? or write another class that calls it 25,000 times? But:

> I just want to test my server how many connections it will accept without any delays

This test won't test that, as all the connections are sequential: each previous connection is closed by the program exiting before the next one starts. If your server doesn't pass that test there is something very seriously wrong with it. A more interesting test would be how many *concurrent* connections it can handle.