# Waiting for parallel batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, parallel-processing

I have 4 batch files. I want to run `one.bat` and `two.bat` at once, concurrently. After completion of these two batch files, `three.bat` and `four.bat` should run at once, in parallel. I tried with many ways but mot works fine.

Can anyone help me over this?

Answer (score 18):

This is easily done using a much simplified version of a solution I provided for [Parallel execution of shell processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715437/1012053). Refer to that solution for an explanation of how the file locking works.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "lock=%temp%\wait%random%.lock"

:: Launch one and two asynchronously, with stream 9 redirected to a lock file.
:: The lock file will remain locked until the script ends.
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%1" one.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%2" two.bat

:Wait for both scripts to finish (wait until lock files are no longer locked)
1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1
for %%N in (1 2) do (
  ( rem
  ) 9>"%lock%%%N" || goto :Wait
) 2>nul

::delete the lock files
del "%lock%*"

:: Launch three and four asynchronously
start "" cmd /c three.bat
start "" cmd /c four.bat
```

Comment: This worked great for my needs. Thank you!
What I also needed was to ensure those commands ran with success. So it looks more like:
    start "" 9>"%lock%1" CMD /C "one.bat > one-log.txt 2>&1 && echo success > one-success.txt"
... then, ensure that each -success.txt file exists, and type the output from each -log.txt.

Comment: @macetw i would like to see your solution that checks for success in a code block so that it is readable.  Could you edit the answer above or submit your code block as an answer?

Comment: to wait you can use [`1>nul 2>nul timeout 1` instead of ping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - Absolutely, though you might want to also throw in the `/nobreak`option. However, TIMEOUT is not available to XP, and that had a significant market share when this answer was written. Thankfully, XP is becoming less and less prevalent now that it is no longer supported.

Comment: Regarding your wait line: `1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1` What does the `::1` do?

Comment: @phonetagger that's the [IPv6 loopback address](https://serverfault.com/q/193377/343888)

Answer (score 6):

I had this same dilemma. Here's the way I solved this issue.
I used the Tasklist command to monitor whether the process is still running or not:

```
:Loop
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq <AAA>" /fi "Windowtitle eq <BBB>"|findstr /i /C:"<CCC>" >nul && (
timeout /t 3
GOTO :Loop
)
echo one.bat has stopped
pause
```

You'll need to tweak the

`<AAA>, <BBB>, <CCC>`

values in the script so that it's correctly filtering for your process.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Create a master.bat file that starts one.bat and two.bat. When one.bat and two.bat end correctly, they echo to file they have finished

```
if errorlevel 0 echo ok>c:\temp\OKONE
if errorlevel 0 echo ok>c:\temp\OKTWO
```

Then the master.bat wait for the existence of the two files

```
del c:\temp\OKONE
del c:\temp\OKTWO
start one.bat
start two.bat
:waitloop
if not exist c:\temp\OKONE (
    sleep 5
    goto waitloop
    )
if not exist c:\temp\OKTWO (
    sleep 5
    goto waitloop
    )
start three.bat
start four.bat
```

Another way is to try with the /WAIT flag

```
start /WAIT one.bat
start /WAIT two.bat
```

but you don't have any control on errors.

Here's some references

http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html

http://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html

http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: `start /WAIT xxx` waits for xxx to finish before letting execution pass to the next line in the batch file. So `one.bat` would have to finish before `two.bat` could even start. You COULD assume that `one.bat` will always finish first and use `start /wait two.bat`, but that's quite an assumption. BTW, you don't have to `start four.bat`, you could just `call four.bat`, (or even leave off the `call` if nothing else is to be done after executing `four.bat` ) and save the memory that would be used by launching another command processor.

Comment: Marked as useful for the approach shared before the mention of start /WAIT. Also make sure you delete those files from master.bat before you start one.bat and two.bat.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, edited the post accordingly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another way, maybe the shortest.

```
(one.cmd | two.cmd) && (three.cmd | four.cmd)
```

Concept is really straight forward. Start one and 2 in paralel, once done and `errorlevel` is `0` run three and four.