# Only first lambda update statement is running in my batch file

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, aws-lambda

Environment:
Windows 10
Command prompt

Why is only the first lambda update running in my batch file? Is this an asynchronous issue?

**script.bat**

```
...
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name "fx1" --zip-file fileb://zip1.zip
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name "fx2" --zip-file fileb://zip2.zip
```

Comment: try `call aws lambda ....` I guess, `aws` is a  batchfile itself. If you just start it like you do, you transfer control to it - there is no "coming back" to execute the next line. `call`ing is - well - *calling* it and continues with the next line, once the called script is finished.

Comment: that worked! if you put it in the answer i'll check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, `aws` is a batchfile:

When you execute another batchfile (B) from a batchfile (A), you transfer control from (A) to (B) and if (B) ends, there is no "return" to (A).

When you [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) the batchfile (B), (A) is paused until (B) finishes; Control is given back to (A) and (A) proceeds with the next line.

So you shouldn't *execute* aws:

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name "fx1" --zip-file fileb://zip1.zip
```

but *call* it:

```
call aws lambda update-function-code --function-name "fx1" --zip-file fileb://zip1.zip
```