# Multithread Batch Queue. How do?

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, queue

How do this?

z1.bat
z2.bat
z3.bat
z4.bat
z5.bat
z6.bat
z7.bat
...
z20.bat

How to run multithread? 5 files run, finish; next 5 files run, finish; next...

Comment: in Linux I'd say http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ or maybe Xargs

Comment: See [Waiting for parallel batch scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665498/1012053) for a robust technique that works with Windows batch files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%b in (1=1=20) do (
      set /a wait_bat=%%b%%5
      if !wait_bat! equ 0 (
        start /w z%%b.bat
      ) else (
         start z%%b.bat
      )

)
endlocal
```

Comment: No, this assumes that the 5th process does not finish before the others. If running 10 script, you could end up with 9 running simultaneously if the 5th is very fast compared to others.