# Batch file runs multiple processes simultaneously

Tags: windows, batch-file, multiprocessing, batch-processing, simultaneous

I need to run similiar multiple mp3 converting processes at the same time with windows command  prompt.
As far as I know, if I start one converting process using batch file, only 1 console window apears and only one process starts. After this process is finished (and if there is a command line for it) starts another process and so on.

As I just tested, if I start multiple batch files at the same time, I have more then 75% time economy!!!!! It's very important form me, because overall time processing counts in months (in my case)!

So, my problem is - how to force start all other multiple batch files at the same time and make the main batch file wait for finished executing all others batches. And only then continiue actions in main batch file.

THANK YOU!

Comment: According to the information provided it is not possible to answer to your question in detail. Anyway, I can broadly say that it is almost certainly not possible what you are looking for: when you call a batch script from another, you create a parallel session, not a subordered one. So, it is not possible to send or receive data through separated sessions and then you are not able to say to a session that the other ones have accomplished their tasks.

Comment: @dbenham Dave, was it you that developed a multiple process batch file?  I'm not sure where it was posted.

Comment: [dbenham - Robust](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes/11715437#11715437) and [short](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577442/waiting-for-parallel-batch-scripts/12665498#12665498)

Comment: @IrRelevant Thanks, that's the one.  Євген Євтушенко can examine the scripts.

Comment: That's a really ingenious trick!
+1 well deserved!

Comment: Rodolfo Cangiotti, Ir Relevant, foxidrive - you guys are AWESOME. Thank you very much. I will try this solution now. I am newbie in batch files programming. So if I will have difficulties, I hope you can show me the right way. THANKS AGAIN!