# Batch - Wait a list of processes to end

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing

I have a .bat script that operates this way:

- Launches build scripts for each webpack project in a directory
- Waits 30 seconds
- Runs the server hosting the project
- Opens Chrome with a tab for every project

I would like to avoid to wait 30 seconds and run the server as soon as all building processes have ended. How can I do this?

This is the code of my batch script:

```
@echo off
cd webapp
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set params=
FOR /D %%G IN ("*") DO (
 cd %%G
 @echo on
 svn update
 call npm install
 start /B npm run dev
 @echo off
 set params=!params! http://localhost:9000/%%G
 cd ..
)
cd ..
timeout /t 30 /nobreak
@echo on
start /B node core/server.js
start chrome /new-window !params!
```

**EDIT:** the very difficult thing here is that `npm run dev` is a non-ending process: it keeps alive and keeps watching for changes in code. This is its code:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack --config dev.config.js --watch
```

**EDIT N.2:**

To know when build process ends (@SomethingDark) I can change my code like this:

```
@echo off
cd webapp
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

#here I don't have the watch option, so it closes on build finished
set params=
FOR /D %%G IN ("*") DO (
 cd %%G
 @echo on
 svn update
 call npm install
 start /B npm run build-dev
 @echo off
 set params=!params! http://localhost:9000/%%G
 cd ..
)
cd ..
timeout /t 30 /nobreak
@echo on
start /B node core/server.js
start chrome /new-window !params!


    #here I have the watch option, so it keeps alive
    FOR /D %%G IN ("*") DO (
     cd %%G
     @echo on
     start /B npm run dev
     @echo off
     cd ..
    )
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a smartass, have you tried removing the `timeout` command?

Comment: It doesn't work because it would launch the server and the browser as soon as it has launched all building processes (and they take some time to complete)

Comment: If `npm run dev` never stops, how do you know when it's done?

Comment: Please check edit :)

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549269/batch-processing-multiple-files-at-the-same-time/49551035#49551035) and first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44697124/2152082) for some inspiration.