# Batch script - Run exe program one after another

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some EXE programs,Want to run using batch file one after another.

Actually one set contains 2 EXE programs with some parameters.

```
Example.

@echo off  
start prog1.exe
start prog2.exe

/---wait untill prog1.exe and prog2.exe finish--/

start prog3.exe
start prog4.exe
```

Comment: You don't know how much time to wait. Could you just run prog1.exe and prog2.exe sync one after another and than prog3.exe and proc4.exe simultanously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallel execution of shell processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes)

Comment: This is called a "rendezvous". You have to wait for _two_ processes.

Answer (score 8):

To run the .exes sequentually you need to pass the /wait parameter to start

e.g.

```
@echo off  
start /wait prog1.exe
start /wait prog2.exe
start /wait prog3.exe
start /wait prog4.exe
```

However that does not run start1 and 2 in parallel. For more complex use see answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes)

Comment: I think you wanted to write start prog3.exe and start prog4.exe without /wait.

Comment: @LukeCodeBaker possibly valid as well but the OP is not that clear

Comment: @Mark - i am looking 2 programs in parallel.

Comment: What about running prog3 and prog4 in a different batch?

Answer (score 0):

you don't even need the "start /wait". it will automatically call the program and wait if you just put "progx.exe"