# for and start commands in a batch for parallel and sequential work

Tags: multithreading, batch-file

I have an 8 core CPU with 8GB of RAM, and I'm creating a batch file to automate 7-zip CLI in exhausting most parameters and variables to compress the same set of files with the ultimate goal of finding the strongest combination of parameters and variables that result in the smallest archive size possible.

This is very time consuming by nature especially when the set of files to be processed is in gigabytes. I need a way not only to automate but to speed up this whole process.

7-zip works with different compression algorithms, some are single-threaded only, and some are multi-threaded, some do not require much amount of memory, and some require huge amounts of it and could even surpass the 8GB barrier. I've already successfully created an automated batch that works in sequence which exclude combinations requiring more than 8GB of memory.

I've split the different compression algorithms in several batches to simplify the whole process. For example, compression in PPMd as a 7z archive uses 1-thread and up to 1024MB. This is my current batch:

```
@echo off
echo mem=1m 2m 3m 4m 6m 8m 12m 16m 24m 32m 48m 64m 96m 128m 192m 256m 384m 512m 768m 1024m
echo o=2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 12 14 16 20 24 28 32
echo s=off 1m 2m 4m 8m 16m 32m 64m 128m 256m 512m 1g 2g 4g 8g 16g 32g 64g on
echo x=1 3 5 7 9

for %%x IN (9) DO for %%d IN (1024m 768m 512m 384m 256m 192m 128m 96m 64m 48m 32m 24m 16m 12m 8m 6m 4m 3m 2m 1m) DO for %%w IN (32 28 24 20 16 14 12 10 8 7 6 5 4 3 2) DO for %%s IN (on) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.ppmd.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -m0=PPMd:mem=%%d:o=%%w -ms=%%s
exit
```

`x`, `s`, `o` and `mem` are parameters, and what's after each of them are the variables which 7z.exe will work with. `x` and `s` in this case are of no concern, they mean compression strength and solid block size for the archive.

That batch will work fine, but is limited to running only 1 instance of 7z.exe at a time and now I'm looking for a way to make it run more 7z.exe instances in parallel but without exceeding 8GB of RAM or 8 threads at once, whichever comes first, before proceeding to do the next ones in the sequence.

How can I improve this? I have some ideas but I don't know how to make them work in a batch. I was thinking of 2 other variables that won't interact with the 7z processes but would control when the next 7z instance would start. One variable would keep track of how many threads are currently in use and another would track how much memory are in use. Could that work?

Edit:
Sorry, I need to add details, I'm new to this posting style. Following this answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481253/2896127 - I mentioned 8 batches were created and that 7z.PPMd batch was one of them. Maybe listing all the batches and how 7z deals with the parameters will give a better insight on the whole issue. I'll start with the simple ones:

- 7z.PPMd - 1 fully utilized thread and dictionary dependant 32m-1055m memory usage per instance.
- 7z.BZip2 - 8 fully utilized threads and fixed 109m memory usage per instance.
- zip.Bzip2 - 8 partially utilized threads and fixed 336m memory usage per instance.
- zip.Deflate - 8 partially utilized threads and fixed 260m memory usage per instance.
- zip.PPMd - 8 partially utilized threads and dictionary dependant 280m-2320m memory usage per instance.

What I mean with partially utilized threads is that, while I assign 8 threads to be used by each 7.exe instance, the algorithm can do variable CPU usage at a randomly fashion, out of my control, unpredictable, but the limitation is set there - no more than 8 threads. In the case of 8 fully utilized threads, it means that on my 8 core CPU, each instance is utilizing 100% of CPU.

The most complex ones - 7z.LZMA, 7z.LZMA2, zip.LZMA - will need to be explained in detail but I am running short on time now. I'll be back to edit the LZMA part whenever I have more free time.

Thanks again.

---

EDIT: Adding in LZMA part.

- 7z.LZMA - each instance is n-threaded, ranging from 1 to 2:

  - 1 fully utilized thread, dictionary dependant, 64k to 512m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 32m memory
    - ...
    - 512m dictionary uses 5407m memory
    - excluded range: 768m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 2 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 512m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 38m memory
    - ...
    - 512m dictionary uses 5413m memory
    - excluded range: 768m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
- 7z.LZMA2 - each instance is n-threaded, ranging from 1 to 8:

  - 1 fully utilized thread, dictionary dependant, 64k to 512m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 32m memory
    - ...
    - 512m dictionary uses 5407m memory
    - excluded range: 768m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 2 or 3 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 512m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 38m memory
    - ...
    - 512m dictionary uses 5413m memory
    - excluded range: 768m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 4 or 5 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 256m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 51m memory
    - ...
    - 256m dictionary uses 5677m memory
    - excluded range: 384m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 6 or 7 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 192m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 62m memory
    - ...
    - 192m dictionary uses 6965m memory
    - excluded range: 256m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 8 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 128m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 72m memory
    - ...
    - 128m dictionary uses 6717m memory
  - excluded range: 192m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
- zip.LZMA - each instance is n-threaded, ranging from 1 to 8:

  - 1 fully utilized thread, dictionary dependant, 64k to 512m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 3m memory
    - ...
    - 512m dictionary uses 5378m memory
    - excluded range: 768m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 2 or 3 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 512m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 9m memory
    - ...
    - 512m dictionary uses 5384m memory
    - excluded range: 768m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 4 or 5 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 256m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 82m memory
    - ...
    - 256m dictionary uses 5456m memory
    - excluded range: 384m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 6 or 7 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 256m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 123m memory
    - ...
    - 256m dictionary uses 8184m (very close to the limit though, I may consider excluding it)
    - excluded range: 384m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)
  - 8 partially utilized threads, dictionary dependant, 64k to 128m:

    - 64k dictionary uses 164m memory
    - ...
    - 128m dictionary uses 5536m memory
    - excluded range: 192m to 1024m (above the limit of 8192m memory available)

---

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the commands with nul in them. I don't quite understand what's happening during that part, what those symbols ^ > ^&1 "" are meant to say.

```
    2>nul del %lock%!nextProc!
    %= Redirect the lock handle to the lock file. The CMD process will     =%
    %= maintain an exclusive lock on the lock file until the process ends. =%
    start /b "" cmd /c %lockHandle%^>"%lock%!nextProc!" 2^>^&1 !cpu%%N! !cmd!
  )
  set "launch="
```

Then later on, at the :wait code:

```
    ) 9>>"%lock%%%N"
  ) 2>nul
  if %endCount% lss %startCount% (
    1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1
    goto :wait
  )

2>nul del %lock%*
```

---

EDIT 2 (29-10-2013): Adding the current point of the situation.

After trial and error research, complemented with step by step notes of what's happening, I was able to understand the behaviour above. I simplified the line with start command to this:

```
start /b /low cmd /c !cmd!>"%lock%!nextProc!"
```

Though it works, I still don't understand the meaning of `1^>"filename" 2^>^&1 'command'`. I know it is related to writing text in the filename what would otherwise be displayed to me. In this case, it would show all of 7z.exe text but written in the file. Until 7z.exe instance finishes its job, nothing is written in the file, but the file already exists, yet at the same time doesn't exist. When 7z.exe actually finishes, the file is finalized and this time it exists for the next part of the script.

Now I can understand the processing behaviour of the suggested script and I'm complementing it with something of my own - I am trying to implement all batches into "one batch do it all" script. In the simplified version, this is it:

```
echo 8 threads - maxproc=1
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (8) DO for %%d IN (900k) DO for %%s IN (on) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.bzip2.%%tt.%%dd.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=BZip2:d=%%d:mt=%%t
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (8) DO for %%d IN (900k) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.bzip2.%%tt.%%dd.zip .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -mm=BZip2:d=%%d -mmt=%%t
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (8) DO for %%w IN (257 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.deflate64.%%tt.%%ww.zip .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -mm=deflate64:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (8) DO for %%w IN (258 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.deflate.%%tt.%%ww.zip .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -mm=deflate:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (8) DO for %%d IN (256m 128m 64m 32m 16m 8m 4m 2m 1m) DO for %%w IN (16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.ppmd.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.zip .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -mm=PPMd:mem=%%d:o=%%w -mmt=%%t

echo 4 threads - maxproc=2
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (4) DO for %%d IN (256m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO for %%s IN (on) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma2.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=lzma2:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t

echo 2 threads - maxproc=4
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (2) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO for %%s IN (on) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=LZMA:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (2) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO for %%s IN (on) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma2.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=lzma2:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (2) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.zip .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -mm=lzma:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t

echo 1 threads - maxproc=8
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (1) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO for %%s IN (on) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=LZMA:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (1) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO for %%s IN (on) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma2.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=lzma2:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%d IN (1024m 768m 512m 384m 256m 192m 128m 96m 64m 48m 32m 24m 16m 12m 8m 6m 4m 3m 2m 1m) DO for %%w IN (32 28 24 20 16 14 12 10 8 7 6 5 4 3 2) DO for %%s IN (on) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.ppmd.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -m0=PPMd:mem=%%d:o=%%w -ms=%%s
for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (1) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.zip .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -mm=lzma:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t
```

In short, I want to process all that in the most efficient manner possible. Doing it by deciding how many processes can run at a time would be a way, but then there's also the memory required for each process, so that the sum of all required memory by those processes won't exceed 8192 MB. I got this part working.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "maxMem=8192"
set "maxThreads=8"

:cycle1
set "cycleCount=4"
set "cycleThreads=1"
set "maxProc="
set /a "maxProc=maxThreads/cycleThreads"
set "cycleFor1=for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (1) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO for %%s IN (on) DO ("
set "cycleFor2=for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (1) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO for %%s IN (on) DO ("
set "cycleFor3=for %%x IN (9) DO for %%d IN (1024m 768m 512m 384m 256m 192m 128m 96m 64m 48m 32m 24m 16m 12m 8m 6m 4m 3m 2m 1m) DO for %%w IN (32 28 24 20 16 14 12 10 8 7 6 5 4 3 2) DO for %%s IN (on) DO ("
set "cycleFor4=for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (1) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO ("
set "cycleCmd1=7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=LZMA:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t"
set "cycleCmd2=7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma2.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=lzma2:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t"
set "cycleCmd3=7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.ppmd.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -m0=PPMd:mem=%%d:o=%%w -ms=%%s"
set "cycleCmd4=7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.zip .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -mm=lzma:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t"
set "tempMem1=5407"
set "tempMem2=5407"
set "tempMem3=1055"
set "tempMem4=5378"
rem set "tempMem1=5407"
rem set "tempMem2=5407"
rem set "tempMem3=1055 799 543 415 287 223 159 127 95 79 63 55 47 43 39 37 35 34 33 32"
rem set "tempMem4=5378"
set "memSum=0"
if not defined memRem set "memRem=!maxMem!"

for /l %%N in (1 1 %cycleCount%) DO (set "tempProc%%N=")
for /l %%N in (1 1 %cycleCount%) DO (
  set memRem
  set /a "tempProc%%N=%memRem%/tempMem%%N"
  set /a "memSum+=tempMem%%N"
  set /a "memRem-=tempMem%%N"
  set /a "maxProc=!tempProc%%N!"
  call :executeCycle
  set /a "memRem+=tempMem%%N"
  set /a "memSum-=tempMem%%N"
  set /a "maxProc-=!tempProc%%!
)
goto :fim

:executeCycle
set "lock=lock_%random%_"
set /a "startCount=0, endCount=0"
for /l %%N in (1 1 %maxProc%) DO set "endProc%%N="

    set launch=1
    for %%x IN (9) DO for %%t IN (1) DO for %%d IN (512m) DO for %%w IN (273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8) DO for %%s IN (on) DO (
      set "cmd=7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.lzma.%%tt.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -ms=%%s -m0=LZMA:d=%%d:fb=%%w -mmt=%%t"
      if !startCount! lss %maxProc%  (
        set /a "startCount+=1, nextProc=startCount"
      ) else (
        call :wait
      )
      set cmd!nextProc!=!cmd!
      echo !time! - proc!nextProc!: starting !cmd!
      2>nul del %lock%!nextProc!
      start /b /low cmd /c !cmd!>"%lock%!nextProc!"
    )
    set "launch="
:wait
        for /l %%N in (1 1 %startCount%) do (
          if not defined endProc%%N if exist "%lock%%%N" (
            echo !time! - proc%%N: finished !cmd%%N!
            if defined launch (
              set nextProc=%%N
              exit /b
            )
            set /a "endCount+=1, endProc%%N=1"
          ) 9>>"%lock%%%N"
        ) 2>nul
        if %endCount% lss %startCount% (
        1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1
        goto :wait
      )

2>nul del %lock%*
echo ===
echo Thats all folks!
exit /b
:fim
pause
```

I have trouble with `cycleFor1` and `cycleCmd1` located in `:cycle1` part - they should be replacing the `for` line and the first `cmd` variable inside the `:executeCycle`, to make it work as I intend to. How do I do that?

The other issue I have is about `tempMem3`. I have logged all memory required when the command `cycleCmd3` would be running. It is dictionary dependant. tempMem3 and cycleCmd3 are related like this:

```
for %%d IN (1024m 768m 512m 384m 256m 192m 128m 96m 64m 48m 32m 24m 16m 12m 8m 6m 4m 3m 2m 1m) DO
set "tempMem3=1055 799 543 415 287 223 159 127 95 79 63 55 47 43 39 37 35 34 33 32"
```

So 1024m would use 1055, 768m would use 799, and so on till 1m using 32. I don't know how to translate that into the script.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why you are doing that? instead setting yourself the dictionary size and other parametters if you want the better/efficient and performance balanced algorithm compression why not use the 7ZIP "MAX" standard profile?

Comment: In was traditional wisdom that the byte composition of the source files affects the compression size too - so settings that might be optimal for one set of test files could be suboptimal for another set of source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already posted a robust batch solution that limits the number of parallel processes at [Parallel execution of shell processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715437/1012053). That script uses a list of commands that is embedded within the script. Follow the link to see how it works.

I modified that script to generate the commands using FOR loops as per your question. I also set the limit to 8 simultaneous processes.

Your maximum memory is 1g, and you never have more than 8 processes, so I don't see how you could ever exceed 8g. If you increase the max memory per processes, then you do have to worry about total memory. you will have to add additional logic to keep track of how much memory is being used, and which cpu IDs are available. Note that batch numbers are limited to ~2g, so I recommend computing memory used in megabytes.

By default, the script hides the output of the commands. If you want to see the output, then run it with the `/O` option.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Display the output of each process if the /O option is used
:: else ignore the output of each process
if /i "%~1" equ "/O" (
  set "lockHandle=1"
  set "showOutput=1"
) else (
  set "lockHandle=1^>nul 9"
  set "showOutput="
)

:: Define the maximum number of parallel processes to run.
:: Each process number can optionally be assigned to a particular server
:: and/or cpu via psexec specs (untested).
set "maxProc=8"

:: Optional - Define CPU targets in terms of PSEXEC specs
::           (everything but the command)
::
:: If a cpu is not defined for a proc, then it will be run on the local machine.
:: I haven't tested this feature, but it seems like it should work.
::
:: set cpu1=psexec \\server1 ...
:: set cpu2=psexec \\server1 ...
:: set cpu3=psexec \\server2 ...
:: etc.

:: For this demo force all cpu specs to undefined (local machine)
for /l %%N in (1 1 %maxProc%) do set "cpu%%N="

:: Get a unique base lock name for this particular instantiation.
:: Incorporate a timestamp from WMIC if possible, but don't fail if
:: WMIC not available. Also incorporate a random number.
  set "lock="
  for /f "skip=1 delims=-+ " %%T in ('2^>nul wmic os get localdatetime') do (
    set "lock=%%T"
    goto :break
  )
  :break
  set "lock=%temp%\lock%lock%_%random%_"

:: Initialize the counters
  set /a "startCount=0, endCount=0"

:: Clear any existing end flags
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %maxProc%) do set "endProc%%N="

:: Launch the commands in a loop
  set launch=1
  echo mem=1m 2m 3m 4m 6m 8m 12m 16m 24m 32m 48m 64m 96m 128m 192m 256m 384m 512m 768m 1024m
  echo o=2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 12 14 16 20 24 28 32
  echo s=off 1m 2m 4m 8m 16m 32m 64m 128m 256m 512m 1g 2g 4g 8g 16g 32g 64g on
  echo x=1 3 5 7 9
  for %%x IN (9) DO for %%d IN (1024m 768m 512m 384m 256m 192m 128m 96m 64m 48m 32m 24m 16m 12m 8m 6m 4m 3m 2m 1m) DO (
    set "cmd=7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.ppmd.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -m0=PPMd:mem=%%d:o=%%w -ms=%%s"
    if !startCount! lss %maxProc% (
      set /a "startCount+=1, nextProc=startCount"
    ) else (
      call :wait
    )
    set cmd!nextProc!=!cmd!
    if defined showOutput echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo !time! - proc!nextProc!: starting !cmd!
    2>nul del %lock%!nextProc!
    %= Redirect the lock handle to the lock file. The CMD process will     =%
    %= maintain an exclusive lock on the lock file until the process ends. =%
    start /b "" cmd /c %lockHandle%^>"%lock%!nextProc!" 2^>^&1 !cpu%%N! !cmd!
  )
  set "launch="

:wait
:: Wait for procs to finish in a loop
:: If still launching then return as soon as a proc ends
:: else wait for all procs to finish
  :: redirect stderr to null to suppress any error message if redirection
  :: within the loop fails.
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %startCount%) do (
    %= Redirect an unused file handle to the lock file. If the process is    =%
    %= still running then redirection will fail and the IF body will not run =%
    if not defined endProc%%N if exist "%lock%%%N" (
      %= Made it inside the IF body so the process must have finished =%
      if defined showOutput echo ===============================================================================
      echo !time! - proc%%N: finished !cmd%%N!
      if defined showOutput type "%lock%%%N"
      if defined launch (
        set nextProc=%%N
        exit /b
      )
      set /a "endCount+=1, endProc%%N=1"
    ) 9>>"%lock%%%N"
  ) 2>nul
  if %endCount% lss %startCount% (
    1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1
    goto :wait
  )

2>nul del %lock%*
if defined showOutput echo ===============================================================================
echo Thats all folks!
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. I was going to comment earlier, but I was deciphering your solution. It appears to work great for 7z format with PPMd algorithm. I simplified memory usage for this, but the real memory usage for each instance appears to be 32m+mem, so for whenever the dictionary size is set to 1024m, it is in reality using 1056m, if it is set to 1m size, it is using 33mb memory.

This was just one of my eight different batches. I was trying to start from somewhere, being 7z.PPMd batch the slowest in my tests due to its single-threaded nature.

Answer (score 1):

To execute at the same time no more than 8 instances of `7z.exe` process you could do this:

```
@Echo OFF & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set /A "pCount=0" & REm Process count

For
...
) DO (
     Set /A "pCount+=1"
     If !pCount! LEQ 8 (
       Start /B 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.ppmd.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -m0=PPMd:mem=%%d:o=%%w -ms=%%s
     )
)
...
```

If do you want to run each process in a new parallel CMD window then you would replace the `Start /B` line on my code for this else:

```
CMD /C "Start /w 7z.exe a teste.resultado\%%xx.ppmd.%%dd.%%ww.%%ss.7z .\teste.original\* -mx=%%x -m0=PPMd:mem=%%d:o=%%w -ms=%%s"
```

Comment: I just tried this. It runs the first 8 instances but no more than that. The 2nd option with CMD /C only runs 1 at a time and when the 8th finishes, it doesn't do anything more.