# Svg to png many files conversion using Inkscape from batch file

Tags: batch-file, inkscape

I have a folder containing many svg files and I would like to convert them to png files using inkscape with a batch script (Windows 10 `*.bat` file). 
the following script works correctly for a single file but, how to iterate the same command for hundreds of files inside a directory?

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files\Inkscape"

inkscape myfile.svg --export-png=myfile.png
```

Comment: You can do that with **ImageMagick** by the way `magick mogrify -format PNG *.svg` will convert all SVGs in current directory to PNG format.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```bash
@echo off
for %%i in ("%~dp0*.svg") do (
    echo %%i to %%~ni.png
    "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.exe" --export-type="png" "%%i"
)
```

Additional options for export are listed in this [Wiki page](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line#Export_files), and in the [man page](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html) (official documentation): in particular, you can set the DPI, height/width, what zone you export, etc.

To speed things up by utilizing all of your logic cores, you can use this multitasking approach:
[Parallel execution of shell processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455439/86145)

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define the command that will be run to obtain the list of files to process
set listCmd=dir /b /a-d "%~dp0*.svg"

:: Define the command to run for each file, where "%%F" is an iterated file name from the list
::   something like YOUR_COMMAND -in "%%F" -out "%%~nF.ext"
set runCmd=""C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.exe" --export-type="png" "%%F""

:: Define the maximum number of parallel processes to run.
set "maxProc=%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%"

::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: The remainder of the code should remain constant
::

:: Get a unique base lock name for this particular instantiation.
:: Incorporate a timestamp from WMIC if possible, but does not fail if
:: WMIC not available. Also incorporate a random number.
  set "lock="
  for /f "skip=1 delims=-+ " %%T in ('2^>nul wmic os get localdatetime') do (
    set "lock=%%T"
    goto :break
  )
  :break
  set "lock=%temp%\lock%lock%_%random%_"

:: Initialize the counters
  set /a "startCount=0, endCount=0"

:: Clear any existing end flags
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %maxProc%) do set "endProc%%N="

:: Launch the commands in a loop
  set launch=1
  for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%F in ('%listCmd%') do (
    if !startCount! lss %maxProc% (
      set /a "startCount+=1, nextProc=startCount"
    ) else (
      call :wait
    )
    set cmd!nextProc!=%runCmd%
    echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo !time! - proc!nextProc!: starting %runCmd%
    2>nul del %lock%!nextProc!
    %= Redirect the lock handle to the lock file. The CMD process will     =%
    %= maintain an exclusive lock on the lock file until the process ends. =%
    start /b "" cmd /c >"%lock%!nextProc!" 2^>^&1 %runCmd%
  )
  set "launch="

:wait
:: Wait for procs to finish in a loop
:: If still launching then return as soon as a proc ends
:: else wait for all procs to finish
  :: redirect stderr to null to suppress any error message if redirection
  :: within the loop fails.
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %startCount%) do 2>nul (
    %= Redirect an unused file handle to the lock file. If the process is    =%
    %= still running then redirection will fail and the IF body will not run =%
    if not defined endProc%%N if exist "%lock%%%N" 9>>"%lock%%%N" (
      %= Made it inside the IF body so the process must have finished =%
      echo ===============================================================================
      echo !time! - proc%%N: finished !cmd%%N!
      type "%lock%%%N"
      if defined launch (
        set nextProc=%%N
        exit /b
      )
      set /a "endCount+=1, endProc%%N=1"
    )
  )
  if %endCount% lss %startCount% (
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
    goto :wait
  )

2>nul del %lock%*
echo ===============================================================================
```

Comment: You could push your output command through ppx, to efectively utilize all CPU cores of your machine http://www.pirosa.co.uk/demo/wxargs/wxargs.html

Comment: @user2956477 Thanks for the parallelization idea. I added a multitasking batch script so you don't have to download xargs or GNU parallel for windows

Answer (score 4):

For people, like me, who land on this question searching for a **Linux method** to "batch" convert .svg pictures into .pdf

Create a `mysvg2pdf.sh` executable file in the directory where your pictures are with following code

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "$PWD"/pdf
for file in $PWD/*.svg
    do
        filename=$(basename "$file")
        inkscape "$file" --export-type=pdf --export-filename="$PWD"/pdf/"${filename%}.pdf"
    done
```

Execute it, `./mysvg2pdf.sh` and a subfolder *pdf* is created with the corresponding .pdf converted files.

(Source: [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/export-multiple-svg-files-generated-with-inkscape-to-multiple-pdf-files#60891))

### Possible code adaptations

- If you want to convert with `inkscape` into another format (as in the original question ;)) just change every appearance of the string `pdf` in the above code for your desired format, e.g., `png`.
- If you have installed *Inkscape* via `flatpak` then substitute the command `inkscape` with the expression `/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=inkscape --file-forwarding org.inkscape.Inkscape` (leave the rest unchanged, i.e., `"$file" --export-type=...`)
- If you want to strip the original `.svg` extension of your files, so that the output file only has `.pdf` instead of `.svg.pdf` change the expression `$(basename "$file")` for `$(basename "$file" | cut -d. -f1)`
- If you want to use another converter, for example the python converter  [cairosvg](https://cairosvg.org/)—which I heartily recommend, because it produces much smaller .pdf files–. Then change the whole inkscape command line `inkscape "$file" ...  "${filename%}.pdf"` for a line with the `cairosvg` command: `cairosvg "$file" -o "$PWD"/pdf/"${filename%}.pdf"`

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed a bit for newer versions of Inkscape in Windows (v1.0 at the time writing).
For command line, you can use **inkscape.com** instead of .exe. This will also work with portable versions. Moreover, the parameter --export-png has been replaced by --export-filename.
So it should simply look like this:

```
FOR %%A IN (*.svg) DO "<path to Inkscape bin>\inkscape.com" %%A --export-filename=%%A.png
```

- The export type should be detected automatically from the file extension. Otherwise you can explicitly specify it with --export-type=png.
- For scaling you can use the parameter --export-dpi=DPI, or via width/height --export-width=WIDTH --export-height=HEIGHT