# How to batch multiple commands such that exactly two are being executed at all times

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing

I am running Windows 10, using a batch file to run multiple processes as shown below.  Each command solves a finite element analysis model that takes an unpredictable amount of time typically in the range of 1 to 5 hours.  My computer is capable of running two analyses simultaneously, so I use the `start` command in every other command.

```
start programName param1
programName param2
start programName param3
programName param4
etc...
```

My problem is that the third command doesn't start until **both** the first and second commands are finished.  I prefer that there would be two commands running at all times.

I have considered running two batch files simultaneously instead as shown below, but then one batch file might finish while the other still has multiple commands waiting to run.

```
[batch1.bat]
programName param1
programName param2
etc...

[batch2.bat]
programName param3
programName param4
etc...
```

**Is there an easy existing method to ensure that there are always exactly two commands running in parallel?**  If not, I will probably work on hacking something together in c++ using the `system` command.

Comment: Perhaps try to get the number of running `programName` processes using `tasklist` and start next one as soon as there are less than two processes found...

Comment: I recommend the [2nd answer to the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11715437/1012053). You can easily modify it to specify the max number of parallel processes, and you should be able to modify the source of the jobs without much trouble.