# Run multiple R scripts concurrently through a batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, rscript

I'm trying to follow the conventional method to trigger R scripts through batch like

RScript Example.R

but what i look to is some way to run multiple R scripts through a batch file.

I tried to do use Start command to open multiple sessions but that doesn't work either. (RScript START ex1.R START ex2.R)

PS complete noob to batch files.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes

Answer (score 4):

On Windows - if you want to run them in parallel make sure you add `start` in yoyr batch (.bat) script. Otherwise `Example2.R` waits for `Example1.R` to complete etc.

```
start RScript Example1.R
start RScript Example2.R
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sh to launch your scripts, this could do it.

```
cd /path_to_script1/
sh script1.sh &
cd /path_to_script2/
sh script2.sh &
cd /path_to_script3/
sh scipt2.sh &
```

This launches parallel R sessions (one for each script) so careful with memory and CPU use. Each script file contains Rscript command.

Comment: As of now I have the statement RScript Example.R in a .bat file and i execute the.bat file. Can i do that with .sh extension given that im on a windows system?

Comment: probably not the best but you can run sh files in windows using cygwin terminal

Answer (score 0):

Simply save the RScript commands in a Windows batch file (.bat) then double-click the file in directory or call it via command line. Below assumes *RScript* is an environment variable.

Batch file *(type below in Notepad and save with extension .bat, not default .txt)*

```
cd "C:\Path\To\Scripts"

RScript Example1.R
RScript Example2.R
RScript Example3.R
RScript Example4.R
RScript Example5.R
```

CMD Command line

```
call myRScriptBatchFile.bat
```

PowerShell Command line

```
cmd.exe /c myRScriptBatchFile.bat
```