# for loop to correctly split a string from arg (batch novice)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I am trying to modify some excellent code for multithreading batch commands, by dbenham : [Parallel execution of shell processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes) (should not be required to read to solve my problem).

It currently takes the commands from reading a file reference. I want to instead send the commands in via arguments. This will basically only need a single for loop to be modified.

The problem is no matter what variations I try I can not get the correct split out of the for-loop. I am obviously missing something basic with delimiters or something despite reading the documentation multiple times. This is likely pretty trivial for a more experienced batch scripter I expect, but I am thoroughly stuck...

### I am certain that the only thing that needs to change is a single for-statement:

(snippet of multithread.bat)

```
 for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /b ":::" "%~f0"') do (
```

This currently does : "Search in the calling script file (from %~f0) for any lines starting with ::: and make each of those %%A in the for-loop".
This works great, but...

I want to modify this to instead take the lines (commands) from arguments, preferably by just parsing from %* (all arguments). The input format and order of arguments are arbitrary so feel free to change it as you want if it makes more sense another way.

### Let me illustrate with a basic example how it might look in practice:

(main script - for illustration)

```
::these are the commands we want to run, ideally I'd like to support an arbitrary number of them
set command1="rclone size remote1:"
set command2="rclone size remote2:"
set command3="rclone size remote3:"

call multithread.bat /O 2 %command1% %command2% %command3%

:: /O indicates we ask for more verbose output from the command controller
:: 2 indicates the desired max amount of conurrently running threads
:: We just want to skip these in the for-loop as they are picked up elsewhere in the script.
```

So what should that for-loop look like to make %%A be command 1,2,3 (and ect. if more commands) ? For example, in the first run of the loop, %%A should in this example be:

rclone size remote1:

then...

rclone size remote2:

the second time ect.

Comment: Your strategy of passing multiple commands on the command line will greatly limit the complexity of your commands - you won't be able to pass commands that take quoted arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `for %%a in (%*) do ...`, but you would have to disregard the first two arguments. Let me suggest another approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion   
set "verbose=%~1"
set "max="%~2"
shift&shift
echo Verbose=%verbose%
echo Maximum=%max%
:loop
if "%~1"=="" goto :continue
echo execute command: %~1
shift
goto :loop
:continue
echo done.
```

Execute as `test.bat /O 2 "rclone size remote1:" "rclone size remote2:" "rclone size remote3:"`

Comment: Thanks, this approach works well. I think I over-complicated it by trying to use for /F with lots of options to do what I needed. To add something constructive here, I might explain that "shift" moves all arguments forward 1 step. Making %2 be the new %1 ect. This is something I did not know until recently, so maybe it will help someone else who reads this :)

Comment: Yes, from time to time, we all are falling into this trap. To be honest, a `for` loop *is* the most obvious approach. But sometimes, "the good old way" fits better.