# How to make by-turn start of .exe files using the .bat-script

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have directory structure:

```
DIR
|-component_name
  |-source
  |-setup.exe
|-another_component_name
  |-source
  |-setup.exe
|-yet_another_component_name
  |-source
  |-setup.exe

and so on...
```

In every directory like "component_name" I have `setup.exe` file which installs current component to the palette component in Delphi. I need to make `DIR/setup.bat` file that would make by-turn start of `setup.exe` in every component directory in `DIR`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you say "by-turn" you mean "one after the other" (i.e., execute the first setup.exe, let it complete, execute the second setup.exe, let it complete, etc).

If setup.exe is **console-based**, then you can just call your .EXEs directly. Each setup.exe will attach to the .BAT file's console window, thus blocking its execution until setup.exe completes. Similar to the for-loop example given by [Bubbafat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008454/how-to-make-by-turn-start-of-exe-files-using-the-bat-script/1008502#1008502):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s setup.exe') do %%i
```

However, if setup.exe is **gui-based**, then you'll have to use the CALL command. This will cause the .BAT file to wait for the called process to terminate before executing any more commands:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s setup.exe') do call %%i
```

---

Now, if I misunderstood you and your EXEs are console-based and you want to execute them all at the same time without waiting for each to complete in turn, then you can use the START command. This will open a new console window for each EXE.

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s setup.exe') do start %%i
```

---

NB: Changed from "for /r" type loop to "for /f" since it will only return existing paths (unlike "for /r", which generates paths that may not exist).

Comment: Thank you!!!
for /r %%i in (setup.exe) do %%i 
Works fine!
Yeah, setup.exe is console-based, but I also need to run Uninstall.bat from each directory "one after the other" (where setup.exe is located). How can I make it with, for example, uninst.bat script? I have read the stackoverflow.com/questions/649634/ but I can't understand how can I run the .bat from another bat in loop. Please, help.

Comment: Just replace "setup.exe" with "uninst.bat". For example:

  for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s uninst.bat') do %%i

Comment: Excuse me, but I've forgotten to say that uninst.bat contains only this string: "setup.exe" /uninstall So I need to run the .bat from another .bat in loop and the last .bat makes execution .exe with key...

Answer (score 1):

**example:**

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b setup.exe') do (
%%i
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking "how do I run every setup.exe in my directory tree?".

If the list is known ahead of time you can just create a batch file that runs the programs one after another.  E.g.

```
component_name\setup.exe
another_component_name\setup.exe
yet_another_component_name\setup.exe
```

But if the list is not static, and the order they run is not important, then you can use a for loop in a batch file like this:

```
for /F %i in ('dir /B /S *.log') do %i
```

To preview what this would do add an "echo" before the last "%i" like:

```
for /F %i in ('dir /B /S *.log') do echo %i
```

If this is not what you meant please clarify what you are asking as it is not clear.

Comment: > I think you are asking "how do I run every setup.exe in my >directory tree?".
Exactly!
What I needed was script:

for /F %i in ('dir /B /S *.exe') do start %i
pause

But I also need to run Uninstall.bat from each directory (where setup.exe is located). How can I make it with this .bat script? I have read the [post]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649634/how-do-i-run-a-bat-file-in-the-background-from-another-bat-file 
but it is all the same - I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for /r %i in (setup.exe) do %i
```

(or, if you embed it into a .bat file, remember to double the % signs)