# How to run multiple DOS commands in parallel?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to run multiple dos commands?

I have a `for` loop, which runs detection of server to detect which server works and is fast. And because there is more servers, I wish not to run all server detections in sequence, but in parallel.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run a bat file in the background from another bat file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649634/how-do-i-run-a-bat-file-in-the-background-from-another-bat-file)

Comment: This one is a complete script using only windows batch features: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11715437/2026975

Comment: [Windows cmd is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There are no such things like for loop or parallel in DOS

Answer (score 243, accepted):

You can execute commands in parallel with `start` like this:

```
start "" ping myserver
start "" nslookup myserver
start "" morecommands
```

They will each start in their own command prompt and allow you to run multiple commands at the same time from one batch file.

Comment: Moreover, the [`/b`](https://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) option allows to execute the `start` command without creating a new window. Try this with cmd: `start /b ping google.com & start /b ping example.com`

Comment: @NinoFiliu you should gain the nobel

Comment: How to wait for last parallel process to complete?

Answer (score 9):

You can execute commands in parallel with `start` command, like:

```
start "" ping google.com
```

But to execute WITHOUT new window, use the [`/b`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) option, like:

```
start /b ping google.com -t
start /b ping example.com -t
```

> Moreover, the `-t` option makes ping repeat infinite times.
>
> Also, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> does not work (but `Ctrl+C` works for above example).

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to see "[How do I run a bat file in the background from another bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649634/how-do-i-run-a-bat-file-in-the-background-from-another-bat-file)"

Also, good answer (of using `start` command) was given in "[Parallel execution of shell processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes)" question page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/676668/889576);

But my recommendation is to use *PowerShell*. I believe it will perfectly suit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

if you have multiple parameters use the syntax as below. I have a bat file with script as below:

```
start "dummyTitle" [/options] D:\path\ProgramName.exe Param1 Param2 Param3 
start "dummyTitle" [/options] D:\path\ProgramName.exe Param4 Param5 Param6
```

This will open multiple consoles.