# C Automatic testing client server program

Tags: c, udp, client-server

I have a client-server program using UDP and I would like to test the connection times in an automated way.

The server closes itself after accepting or rejecting a connection and I can't make changes to the connection related code not for the client, nor the server.

The only thing that comes to my mind is trying to do this from a batch file (I'm in windows), but I don't know if it is possible to run both commands from the same batch file in an automated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to be easier than I thought, actually the problem was formulating the *correct* question: [How to run multiple DOS commands in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010834/how-to-run-multiple-dos-commands-in-parallel)

For the sake of completeness, this is the script I'm using now.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /l %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
    start server.exe
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 2 > nul
    start /wait client.exe
)
```

I start the server and give him 2ms to warm up (if not, some times the client would start up before the server and that instance will fail).
Then I call the client and wait until it's finished.