# Run multiple Gatling Simulations at same time

Tags: gatling

I want to run my multiple Gatling simulations at the same time from Gatling.bat.

Please let me know how is it possible.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You have to run more than one command parallel. So according to [Gatling documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.2/general/configuration.html) and [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11011212/5003181) you could do this for example by:

```
start bin/gatling.bat -s SimulationClass1
start bin/gatling.bat -s SimulationClass2
start bin/gatling.bat -s SimulationClass3
```