# Java, run main method of two class in the same time with script

Tags: java, batch-file, methods, program-entry-point

I'm trying to run more than two main method with a script so I can process them in the same time.

```
@echo off

javac step_0.java
javac step_1.java
javac step_2.java
javac step_3.java
javac step_4_1.java
javac step_4_2.java
javac step_5.java
javac energyConsumption.java

java step_0 && java step_1 && java step_2 && java step_3 && java step_4_1 && java step_4_2 && java step_5 && java energyConsumption

pause
```

This script start with step_0 and need to finish the task to start the step_1...I need them to start at the same time. Thanks

Comment: Call eah of your classes with `start` command as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11011212/1967021

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing each one on background adding "&"?

Answer (score 0):

As @Ivan Pronin proposed it worked!

```
@echo off

javac step_0.java
javac step_1.java
javac step_2.java
javac step_3.java
javac step_4_1.java
javac step_4_2.java
javac step_5.java
javac energyConsumption.java

start step_0
start step_1

pause
```

and two script for step_0 and step_1

```
@echo off

java step_0

pause

@echo off

java step_1

pause
```