# Is there a simple way to have my command line loop execute in parallel?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, parallel-processing, anaconda

I have a Python script that is being executed within the anaconda prompt in a Windows environment. As this script analyses one variable at a time, the command line loops over the files in a folder, and for every file it executes the script once. It is done in this way, as looping within a script eventually results in a memory error. However, running the script for files one by one is too slow, and I could for sure run the script for five files at once, speeding up the proces five times.

I know that there are modules as subprocess and multiprocessing, but I have a feeling there might be a more simplistic way of doing it. Unfortunately I was not able to find one.

The code I am running at this moment is as follows

```
for /F %i in ('dir "Directory_containing_files" /b /s') do (python Executed_script.py -i %i -o "Folder_to_write_output_to")
```

I hope there is some piece of code that could look something like this:

```
for /F %i in ('dir "Directory_containing_files" /b /s') do (python Executed_script.py -i %i -o "Folder_to_write_output_to") -n 10
```

With the desired output that it runs 10 files in parallel.

Comment: Have you looked at Queues?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html

Comment: So you want parallelism without using the python libraries to make it, but instead through the anaconda prompt? Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010834/how-to-run-multiple-dos-commands-in-parallel

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3004811/570918) Not sure if that works in Anaconda Prompt, though.

Comment: take a look at the [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command.

Comment: I was not able to find anything useful in these commands. I solved it with a less elegant solution of running multiple command prompts, and dividing my initial files in multiple folders.