# How to start multiple project from command line?

Tags: c#, .net

If without command line, I can start multiple projects in Visual Studio Community as shown below:

[image]

But using command line, I can only start one project.

[image]

How to start multiple project from command line?

Comment: you just... run multiple processes from multiple terminals; the new tabbed/split "Windows Terminal" (in the MS store) is great for this

Comment: write a batch file and use the `start` command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11011212/1132334