# How to use the start command in a batch file?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch file that starts an app with a lot of command-line parameters:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe" /port:1672 /path:"C:\Code.Net\My App\Iteration 6\REL_6.8.806_PerfEnhanceV\Fusion\Code\CC.Fusion\CC.Fusion.Services" /vpath:"/FusionServices"
```

The problem is that when I run the batch file, the DOS window stays up until the command completes and I would like it to go away.  So I tried using the `start` command, but placing it in front, like this:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe" /port:1672 /path:"C:\Code.Net\My App\Iteration 6\REL_6.8.806_PerfEnhanceV\Fusion\Code\CC.Fusion\CC.Fusion.Services" /vpath:"/FusionServices"
```

But I get an error stating that `Invalid switch - "/port:1672"`

I have also tried escaping the double quotes, but I was not successful.

How do I fix that?

Comment: How do you kick off the batch file? Do you invoke it from the Command Prompt?

Comment: @jimbojw No, just double click on the file.

Comment: Have a look at - https://ss64.com/nt/start.html.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

An extra pair of rabbits' ears should do the trick.

```
start "" "C:\Program...
```

`START` regards the first quoted parameter as the window-title, unless it's the only parameter - and any switches up until the executable name are regarded as `START` switches.

Answer (score 10):

I think this other Stack Overflow answer would solve your problem: *[How do I run a bat file in the background from another bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351295/199163)*

Basically, you use the `/B` and `/C` options:

```
START /B CMD /C CALL "foo.bat" [args [...]] >NUL 2>&1
```

Comment: That question is for calling other batch files asynchronously.  Unfortunately it doesn't solve my specific problem.