# Using "preLaunchTasks" and Naming a Task in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

According to [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging), it is possible to launch a program before debugging:

> To launch a task before the start of each debug session, set the `preLaunchTask` to the *name* of one of the tasks specified in tasks.json.

I've not seen example syntax of a "named" task, but the [schema documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks_appendix) reveals a property called `taskName`.  I tried using that to link my launch.json `preLaunchTasks` to the task, but it didn't work.  When I launched my program, Visual Studio Code reported this error:

> Could not find a unique task 'launch-core'.  Make sure the task exists and that it has a unique name.

My custom "named" task looked something like this:

```
{
    "taskName": "launch-core",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "C:\\utils\\mystuff.exe",
    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,
    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",
}
```

I then tried changing the property name from `taskName` to just `name`, [based on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046411/define-multiple-tasks-in-vscode).  That also didn't work.

Intellisense gives no suggestions of how to name a task.

Does anybody know how to uniquely name a task in the tasks.json file?  What is the syntax?  What is the property name?

Ultimately I'd like to execute two or three node.js processes before my own node.js app is launched.  For example, I'd like to have the following three apps launched before my app is launched into the debugger:

```
sh -c 'cd ./manager/ && node manager.js'
sh -c 'cd ./adapter/ && node adapter.js'
sh -c 'cd ./core/ && node core.js'
```

If I'm working on a Windows box, my task might look something like this:

```
{
    "taskName": "core-launch",
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "start",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": [
        "ACD-Manager",
        "/B",
        "/D",
        "./manager/",
        "node",
        "manager.js"
        ]
}
```

The above task using using the [cmd `start` capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201507/how-to-use-the-start-command-in-a-batch-file).  I'm not sure yet how to make several node tasks launch instead of one, but I can't even get one task to launch because of this task-naming issue.

How do I name a task in the tasks.json file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So, if it's still relevant, or if someone finds this thread with the same problem, I've just figured it out how it works:

In the **tasks.json**, you need to create a **'tasks' array** - code hint will help you with that - which holds an array of objects. Inside an object, you can have the **'taskName'** key-value pair.

Example:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["run-script", "webpack"],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        { 
            "taskName": "runwebpack",
            "suppressTaskName": true
        }
    ]
}
```

In my case, I had to run the `npm run-script webpack` command before running my project. 
In the **launch.json** file, the `"preLaunchTask": "runwebpack"` will work now.

Note: the `suppressTaskName` is true in my example. Omitting it, or setting it to false will result in VS Code appending the `taskName` after the command.

A more general approach would be something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["run-script"],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        { "taskName": "webpack" }
    ]
}
```

With the latter example, you can extend the `tasks` array with other scripts to be run also.

*Hint for my usage*: npm run-script fetches what to do from the **package.json** file's `scripts` object.

Edit: this works with **VS Code 1.3.1**

Comment: FYI, `taskName` has been deprecated in favor of `label`. See [tasks documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Comment: Same with `showOutput`, now you put `presentation` and inside that dict, put `reveal` set to `always`. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Answer (score 57):

FWIW, I'm using **VS Code 1.20.1** and here's how I got my **preLaunchTask** to work:

In `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        ...
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
    }
  ]
}
```

In my `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "build": "tsc"
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

For version 2.0.0 configuration you now use `label` instead of `taskName`.

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    ...
}
...
```

launch.json (My source is in the `src` directory and `tsc` compiles to the `dist` directory):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "Compile",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile",
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "tsc",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 19):

For vscode `1.36.1 (1.36.1)`:

`tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build:tsc",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "build:tsc"
    },
    {
      "label": "clean",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "clean"
    },
    {
      "label": "build",
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn": ["clean", "build:tsc"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/main.js",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Before running `node ${workspaceFolder}/dist/main.js`, the `preLaunchTask` will run `build` task firstly which includes two subtasks: `clean` and `build`.  It will run `clean` task firstly, then run `build` task.

You can specify the label of a task to `preLaunchTask` option.

Comment: Does this mean `build:tsc` will run after `clean`?

Comment: This pattern worked for me on vscode 1.87.1 Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The question title is:

> "Using “preLaunchTasks” and Naming a Task in Visual Studio Code

I needed to define preLaunchTask***s***.

You can config multiple tasks using the dependsOn property described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks)

For example, a compound task in your tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Client Build",
            "command": "gulp",
            "args": ["build"],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/client"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Server Build",
            "command": "gulp",
            "args": ["build"],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/server"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "dependsOn": ["Client Build", "Server Build"]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can find more information about naming tasks [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks).

Answer (score 0):

I've only really seen the taskName used in relation to Gulp; I'm sure there are others but nothing that I have much insight into. Perhaps this can get you off to a start with what you already have?

[Run a pre-launch task in VSCODE](http://tstringer.github.io/javascript/vscode/nodejs/gulpjs/2015/10/14/vscode-prelaunchtask.html)

Comment: the link in the example is not working anymore