# How do I access .env variables in tasks.json within vscode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-tasks

I am trying to use environment variables within task in my `tasks.json` file of a C# project in `vscode`.

In my `launch.json` file I have this code to parse a .env file:

```
"configurations": [
  {
    ...
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
  }
]
```

I then have in the `tasks.json` file this task:

```
{
  "label": "login",
  "command": "sh",
  "type": "shell",
  "args": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/etc/login.sh",
    "${env:USERNAME}",
    "${env:PASSWORD}"
  ]
}
```

This seems to be the code that's implied from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks, however (from testing by echoing in another task) I have found these last two `args` to be blank. After researching online I think I have found the reason, the `configurations..env` is used by the `tasks` themselves rather than being accessible by `task.json` that run and so can't be accessed.

How do I create (use) these `env variables` within the `tasks.json`?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748562/3223785 . 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix

```json
  /**
   * The environment of the executed program or shell. If omitted
   * the parent process' environment is used.
   */
  env?: { [key: string]: string };
```

example

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "diagnostic",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/beam",
                "env": {
                    "FOO": "baz",
                }
            },
            "command": "printenv",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

There is no way I am aware of to pull these from a file like with launch.json

I would open an issue on the vscode repo

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I am using Windows.
I was able to fix it.
The issue for me was, in VSCode I had this setting set:

```
"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe"
```

And this was causing the env to not load properly.
I was able to access the windows settings, that you would set from that windows GUI env variable tool.  But I could not access env variables set in my .bashrc.
I commented out that setting.

I also have the Terminal > Integrated > Default Profile: Windows
set to Git Bash.

With these changes, I was able to access env variables in my .bashrc file.