# vscode passing environment var to args on launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've created task (tasks.json) for setting environment variable as below

```
export SOME_IP_VARIABLE=1.2.3.4
```

my application needs IP parameters so I added args in launch.json as below

```
...
"configuration":[
    ...
    "args":[
        "${env:SOME_IP_VARIABLE}
    ]
...
```

When I print argv value in the application, this prints nothing.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971572/how-do-i-add-environment-variables-to-launch-json-in-vscode

Comment: Environment variables defined in shell scripts only exist for the shell script and any child processes so `SOME_IP_VARIABLE` doesn't exist after your task finishes executing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I thought If I export environment variables, the variables can be shared with launch.json because launch.json calls task. I'm not familiar with linux system so I thought environment variable works just like windows system variable. thanks for your help.

Comment: try to add **env** in launch.json directly

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748562/3223785 . 