# could not find the task: "npm compile"

Tags: json, npm, launch

I am trying to create a smart contract and running a code. First it was giving an error with outfiles, so I  copied a new code for launch.json file as seen in the screenshot. But now, it shows this error and I have tried everything but don't know what to do. Plz help

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ]
        },
        {

            "name": "Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: compile",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/src/**/*.js"
            ],        
        
            "stopOnEntry": false
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Server",
            "port": 6009,
            "restart": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/out/src/**/*.js"
            ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your project misses a `package.json` file that defines `"compile"`.

For example, if you’re trying to compile/build/transpile TypeScript into JavaScript (I cannot really tell what project you’re working on from what you’ve shared) then call the TypeScript compiler, `tsc`, in the `package.json` file’s `"scripts"` section (in your case you seem to try to call a script `"compile"`):

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "compile": "tsc"
     ...
  },
  ...
}
```

EDIT:

I tried `preLaunchTask npm` in google search. It gave a lot of results.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550043 seems to provide a better solution, there should be a `tasks.json` file that defines the task. (Note that your error messages contains the word “task” and so does “`preLaunchTask`“.) Visual Studio Code documentation about Tasks: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks