# How to Start and Terminate HTTP server using a bat file in Jenkins in build step

Tags: jenkins

I Have a bat script that starts a simple node http server .
Here is my scenario

> 1)Start HTTP server using bat file (When i include this in build step
>   in jenkins the jenkins do not move furthur and keep on waiting and
>   does not execute rest of steps) 2) Run some test case 3 )Terminate the
>   HTTP server

Comment: Just set up your bat script as a build step in jenkins.

Comment: I have already done that but since running http server is a waiting job the jenkins keeps on waiting

Comment: Ah, now I see your problem. You should emphasise this a little more in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your batch file starts the HTTP server process in the background, which will prevent Jenkins from waiting.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351295/1980029) to the question on running bat files in the background should be able to help.

Comment: Yes i was able to resolve issue earlier with running scripts in background still i will mark your answer