# Running FFMPEG in background in PHP file

Tags: php, ffmpeg, camera, background-process

Hey I am using ffmpeg to store live camera streaming in PHP.
I have already downloaded the compiled ffmpeg library and just use its path in php to store stream.
The command is :

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "http://10.11.16.120:90/livestream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=&streamid=0&audio=0&filename=" -c:v libx264 -t 10 -an F:\Camera_Videos\video.mp4
```

Now it waits until ffmpeg compeletes its task and then php code will further run but i want to run ffmpeg in background i have also tried this by adding

```
> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

but it didn't work .
Pleae tell , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you on a windows or a linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you basically want to run `ffmpeg` in the background 'asynchronously'.

I was going through a [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649634/how-do-i-run-a-bat-file-in-the-background-from-another-bat-file) SO Post on how to run a *batch* file in background in windows.

So you could put the following code in a file (let's say `foo.bat`)[Untested code]:

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "http://10.11.16.120:90/livestream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=&streamid=0&audio=0&filename=" -c:v libx264 -t 10 -an F:\Camera_Videos\video.mp4
```

And then in your php script you could execute `foo.bat` as per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649937/1083314) using [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [system](https://www.php.net/system).

I haven't tested the approach above. It just might be a good starting point for you. Hope it helps.